# LaTeX Table of Contents formatting

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I'm having trouble getting LaTeX to format my thesis table of contents correctly.  I've tried several different packages and guides from the forums, but haven't made any progress.
The specific issues I would like to fix are: 
- large and bold font for TOC name should be normal font and not bold.
- TOC depth isn't correct.  It won't show sub-sections. 
- dots connecting page number to heading 
- "page" label at top-right of TOC.

```
    \documentclass{book}
    %General Packages
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[labelfont=bf,font={small,it}]{caption}
    \usepackage{changepage}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linktoc=none,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

    %%Bibliography Setup
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[american]{babel}
    \usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

    % toc SETUP
    \usepackage{titletoc}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \usepackage[section]{tocbibind}
    \usepackage{afterpage}

    \usepackage[tocgraduated]{tocstyle}
    \usetocstyle{allwithdot}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

    \begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}
    \frontmatter
    \clearpage
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \listoffigures
    \newpage
    \listoftables

    \mainmatter
    \chapter{Test 1}
    Test Text
    \section*{Sub1}
    Test Text
    \subsection*{SubSub1}
    Test Text
    \chapter{Test2}
    \chapter{Test 3}
    Test Text
    \section*{Sub1}
    Test Text
    \subsection*{SubSub1}
    Test Text
   \backmatter
    \end{document}
```

This is what I would like:
[image: This is what I would like:]

And this is what I currently get:
[image: And this is what I currently get:]

Comment: For displaying subsections, `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` should do the trick.

Comment: Forgive me for my question: why on earth do you have to insert the Table of Contents into the Table of contents?  What information does the gentle reader gain from this input?  It seems more natural, to align the page numbers flush right/ragged left.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf: he already had `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` in his MWE.  But he needs to set it to `4`.  Same to `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}`.

Comment: Another comment: stared section commands like `\subsection*` won't be inserted into the  Table of Content.  A lot of the packages in your MWE are not concerned to your question.  You should consider to leave them aside.  You should put the package `hyperref` towards the end of the packages.  Usually it is the last package.

Comment: @Jan: I agree with you about having the ToC itself listed in the ToC, but it will add a bookmark if `hyperref` is used, so it's quite easy to jump to the ToC using the bookmark panel. Some say the ToC should be listed...well, that's what `memoir` supports, for example, unless `\tableofcontents*` is used

Comment: To the O.P. You're preamble is quite messy, sorry. `hyperref` should be loaded as last one here, and `titletoc`, `tocloft` and `tocbibind` together ... **no good idea**!!!!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: correct me: but I do get an hyperlinked TOC in PDF files, even without incorporating the TOC it into itself ...

Comment: @Jan: Of course, that's possible, with `\pdfbookmark` etc.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice. Is there a way to get '\section*' or '\subsection*' to print in the table of contents?  The sections and sub sections aren't supposed to be numbered (within the body of the thesis), but are supposed to be in the TOC.